# IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor can not handle proxies, e. g. Transactional

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using Spring Integration DSL to create an IntegrationFlow, which contains a custom MessageChannelSpec (PersistentChannelSpec extends PersistentChannelSpec)

```
@Bean
    public PersistentChannelSpec myChannelSpec() {
        return PersistentChannelSpec.name("myChannelSpec")
                .inbound()
                .build();
    }
```

The created component is a PersistentChannel (extends AbstractMessageChannel)
One of the methods is annotated with @Transactional (the overridden start method from Lifecycle)

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Override
    public void start() {
```

This leads to a CGLIB proxy being created in my context.

Now when the DSL flow gets registered, a BeanDefinitionOverrideException will be thrown, because the "instance is not equal to the bean" found in the beanFactory.

[IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/532f323313f1b7cfd9163cf5d60f891cbcbacb40/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/context/IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java#L408)

Am I doing something completely wrong here?

As soon as I take away the @Transactional, the flow will startup as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `@Transactional` must be a responsibility of a message channel implementation. We need to know more details about your `PersistentChannelSpec`: perhaps there are already some other solution for you in the framework. If not we may consider to make some improvement according to your experience and requirements.

As a workaround you can use a simple channel reference instead of that Spec usage directly:

```
.channel("myChannelSpec")
```

Then this bean name is going to be used in the target endpoint and it will be resolved later at runtime.